# Where are the Dragon Balls?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

How do I find the Dragon Balls ? Can I find them multiple times with the same character or do I need to create a new character to find them a second time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to fight other "time patrol". they show up randomly during missions.

The best way to collect the 7 DB is to do the mission 02. After you've defetead the 3 first fighters (krilin, yamsha, tenshinha), one npc can appear near the temple. just challenge him and try to finish him with a final attack, it seems to boost the chance to drop a DB.

to know if you've got a dragon ball after the fight you should have a message saying that you've got a new "key object". if not, you can select "retry" on the menu to be faster.

Of course after you've succesfully got your DB you need to finish the mission and if you fail... no more DB for you this round.

You don't need to do another caracter to collect them again, you can do it as much as you like with your main caracter.